# Brackets download issue

Tags: download, website, brackets

I cant download the latest brackets release when trying to download from *http://brackets.io/* 
[image]
The download doesn't complete and gets stuck at the last..happened like this on both my laptops.

Is http://brackets.io/ not the official brackets website...how come they don't use https ???

Comment: That is the official site. I just tested it myself. It gets stuck just like that for me too. But only for the Windows version. The Linux version downloads without issue.

Comment: Nevermind. It stayed stuck a 0 for awhile but then finally completed.

Comment: @n8te   I waited 10 minutes but still it did not complete ! is it a chrome issue ...what browser are you using ?

Comment: I tested it in Chrome and Edge. Seems like there's a problem even though it did download and it's showing 76MB in my downloads folder. But when I go to launch it won't launch.

Comment: Restarted Windows since it was getting hung up when I tried to install. After the reboot it was able to install without issue. Went ahead and tried the process all over again and it behaved the same way. The install wouldn't launch again and hung up Windows, so I restarted once again and it was able to install it a second time. Not sure how to account for all of that.

Comment: just downloaded on my desktop (win 10 enterprise v1809) and it completed without any issue...the laptops had win 10 home 1803 and pro v1903

Comment: I did this in a Windows 10 virtual machine. Enterprise 1803.

Comment: I just now checked the downloaded file and it takes too long to open...still has some issues ...anyways thanks.